# Changing the opacity of individual form controls in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, opacity

Ok, so what I'm trying to do is have two imageboxes overlapping so that I can align the images in them (based on user input). The problem is I'm not sure if I can adjust the opacity of individual controls so I can only see the topmost control. Of course, I could do image processing and combine the two images into a single image (with the appropriate transparency settings) but doing that on each input operation would be somewhat expensive so I figured doing it on the UI thread would be a lot cheaper.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do transparency at the control level in WPF but not in WinForms - I'd love to hear what others have to say.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in WinForms, transparency effects don't work for overlapping controls.  The best you could do is overlapping forms so you can use the Opacity and TransparencyKey properties.

A far more practical approach is to use *one* PictureBox in which you display a composite image.  Such an image is easy to create with the ColorMatrix class.  You'll find sample code in my answer in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2b4c5c41-8f3c-4e81-9169-78082b80c747/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Kane says, wpf is probably better for this.
Only the `Form` control supports `Opacity` as a property in winforms ([see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(VS.80).aspx)), but you might be able to get away with it if you put your images in sub-forms (I'm really speculating here, haven't tried this.) and play with their opacity.

Good luck